# acunetix security bug "long password denial of service"

Tags: asp.net, security, testing, passwords, long-integer

**hello guys**
i run my asp application in server and check this security test with acunetix 
my application has 1 high security bug ("long password denial of service")
i try some solution to fix it :

```
-add asp validator with 15 character limitation
-check password length with java script
-check password length on server side
-put an captcha on my login page
```

But had no effect and still gives an error "long password denial of service"

whats wrong!?
Do you think that acunetix mad

Comment: درود , I suggest set 2 seconds interval between each request

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Could you please provide us with the attack details that Acunetix has provided you with.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!!!
iis not install full option , server manager says i checked all option and istall all iis features ,
then i test it again and problem solved